# Will I lose my undead traits when I'm resurrected?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, undead, racial-traits, ability-scores

I have a ghost template in our new horror adventure.

If I die (as a ghost) and after that am resurrected, I will return to being human (my race before becoming a ghost). Will I also lose all of the supernatural and undead traits of the ghost template?

Comment: Do you have a link to the specific ghost template you're using? Or if it's from a book, then which book and ideally which page number the template is in.

Comment: @AgentPaper one would assume the core one, but it really doesn't matter for this question.

Comment: I've downvoted you for asking "if I'm not a ghost, do I get ghost traits". This is not a question that should need asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ordinarily, yes**. An undead creature who is destroyed and then resurrected doesn't come back as an undead creature: it comes back as whatever it originally was, not as the undead creature. Nothing prevents it from becoming the same kind of undead again, of course, if the opportunity arises.

**The Ghostwalk campaign setting (initially published for 3e, but an official 3.5e update exists) has a spell called *raise ghost,* specifically for bringing creatures back from the dead as ghosts**. You don't even need to have been a ghost beforehand, as long as you're willing to come back as a ghost. Your soul knows that the spell will bring you back as a ghost, so you can refuse to return if you don't want that to happen.

**This is not a general solution for undead beings, since it can only bring people back as ghosts, and not other types of creatures**. In fact, it requires some reflavoring to work in other campaign settings anyway, because Ghostwalk's ghosts are not undead. But if it gets that reflavoring, it might be just the sort of thing you need for your particular situation.

Answer (score 18):

You will no longer have the template at all. That is, none of its features, whether from type (Undead), subtype (incorporeal), or the specifics of the template. You also no longer count its LA against your effective character level.

Specifically, under the [Undead traits in the *Monster Manual*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#undeadType):

> *Resurrection* and *true resurrection* can affect undead creatures. These spells turn undead creatures back into the living creatures they were before becoming undead.

Comment: Not that I question your answer, but have you got any rules/quotes that support this?

Comment: @Tijnkwan I do now!

Comment: @KRyan Is that the bit that indicates "and you lose your undead template"? I recognise it could be implied by the fact you turn back into what you were before becoming undead (you didn't have the template at that time).

Comment: @doppelgreener Yes, it is. A ghost is not a living creature, and before becoming undead the ghost did not have the ghost template. Templates change what kind of creature you are.

Comment: I am going out on a limb, but I think a Ghost can't normally be a target of those spells. The spell would have to be cast on the dead body. Once that would happen, the ghost would be no more.

Comment: @Ruut The ghost presumably still has a body **somewhere**, though. Failing that, though, *true resurrection* works even if the body has been destroyed, so that works.

Comment: @KRyan Ah, yes, forgot about True Ressurection.